# SparkPost sending with PHPmailer - how do I disable open and click tracking?

Tags: phpmailer, sparkpost

I know that sending emails with SparkPost via the API, I can disable open and click tracking with:

```
options.open_tracking set to false
options.click_tracking set to false
```

However, I'm sending with PHPmailer.  I can't have my email links be converted to gibberish.  I need the actual links, not the SparkPost converted links.  From what I understand, this will be achieved by not tracking opens and clicks with SparkPost email.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `X-MSYS-API` custom header.

```
$x_msys_api = array(
  'options' => array (
    'open_tracking' => false,
    'click_tracking' => false
  )
);

$phpmailer->addCustomHeader('X-MSYS-API', json_encode($x_msys_api));
```

I assumed you've `$phpmailer` object (instance of PHPMailer class), replace it accordingly.

Here is [official documentation](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/smtp-api.html#header-open-and-click-tracking). Here is an [example use](https://github.com/SparkPost/wordpress-sparkpost/blob/master/mailer.smtp.class.php#L42-L43).

Comment: This won't work; the `addCustomHeader` method doesn't accept arrays as header values - you'll get an array to string conversion error. Setting a header sounds like the right approach, but you'll need to format the value correctly first.

Comment: @Synchro sorry, my bad. you're right. you need to use json_encode. i've updated the answer